# THREEJS Sprite repeat texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I've got a sprite and i'm trying to make the texture repeat over and over.

I think I have the right settings but it doesn't seem to be doing what I expect, am I doing something wrong?

Here's my result:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
    var bgTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/bg.png');
    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: bgTexture });

    spriteMaterial.wrapS = spriteMaterial.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    spriteMaterial.map.offset.set( 0, 0 );
    spriteMaterial.map.repeat.set( 10, 1 );

    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
    sprite.position.y = 0;
    sprite.position.y = 0;
    sprite.scale.x = 10;
    sprite.scale.y = 1;
    this.scene.add(sprite);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties `.wrapS` and `.wrapT` have to be set to the [`Texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture) rather than the [`SpriteMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/SpriteMaterial):

<s>`spriteMaterial.wrapS = spriteMaterial.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;`</s>

```
spriteMaterial.map.wrapS = spriteMaterial.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```